# How to open a locked .mdb file that access cannot open it

Tags: python, ms-access, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I've been trying to open the file in the attached image for a week!, but no method seems to work on it!

[image: this image]

I tried recommended ubuntu and python methods but the result is either "This is a corrupted file", "this file is not a microsoft access file", etc.

I know the file is not corrupted, since I was working with [this github repo](https://github.com/RenYurui/Neural-Texture-Extraction-Distribution/tree/main) and I was able to get the results (this .mdb file is created from a .lsb file and some other txt files)

Now I want to feed some of my own photos and I need to read inside of this .mdb file
Do you guys have any suggestions or Am I missing something ?

Comment: Access databases have a file size limit of 2 GB. So your 8 GB file is indeed not a valid Access file.

Comment: I would create a blank new mdb file, and then impot all the tables from the existing database. As suggested here, that file looks too big, and may well not be a mdb file.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thank you so much! I will definitely try this